# How to constrain camera view to DIV element boundaries

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, ar.js

I'm trying to allow some space to add a navigation menu on this AR site but can't override AR.JS default full screen camera view.  My code, which is almost like Jerome's original looks like this:

```
<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden; font-family: Monospace; padding: 20px;'>

    <div id="camera"></div>
<scrpit>
.
.
document.getElementById('camera').appendChild( renderer.domElement );
.
.
</script>
</body>
```

Notice that I added 20px padding on the `body` tag but that padding is completely ignored by the added `video` tag at the end.

Answer (score 0):

As the `video` element is added later, you can either look for the code where it is defined what exactly it adds and how, or your can try to override it. This should work to get the 20px margin on the left:

```
video {
    margin-left: 20px !important;
}
```

But make sure the actual video and AR.js scene are not negatively affected.